# Good form validation in Angular 5

Tags: angular, forms

Good morning everyone,

I want to achieve the following behaviour with an ng5 form:

- When customer touched a form control and the input is invalid, then the form control should be marked as invalid
- When the customer touches no form control and then hits "submit" all form controls should be validated
- The submit button should be always active. I don´t really like the "disable submit button until everything is ok" theory cause it doesn´t tell the user what´s wrong with his inputs

So validation of controls onchange works fine, but what I´m missing is a "form.validate()" method. Also the new "updateOn" feature doesn´t solve this issue, cause then it´s an either-or solution, not a combination of submit- and change validation.

The only solution I found was to develop a validate() method myself which iterates over all controls of a form.

Maybe somebody has an idea for me? :)

Thanks & best,
Michael

Answer (score 1):

The form is a tree of controls and whenever a single control becomes invalid all of its ancestors become invalid as well.
Whenever the input of a control changes (given you did apply validators) the validity of the control **and** the form is updated.
Thus, when you hit `Submit` you don't really need to run validation again (as it was run on each input change).
All you need for "running validation" is check if the form is valid. You can do this by accessing `valid` property of the root `FormGroup`:

```
if(!rootFormGroup.valid)
    showErrorPopup();
else
    submitForm();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Reactive Forms will be good.
You can achieve everything mentioned here..
https://toddmotto.com/angular-2-forms-reactive

```
1. Validation: 
  this.rForm = formBuilder.group({
      'email': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.email])] ....

2. Touch events 
  <div *ngIf="!rForm.controls.email.valid && rForm.controls['email'].touched" class="alert-danger form-alert-bg">
                  <span *ngIf="rForm.controls.email.errors?.required">
                    Email is Required*
                  </span> </div>

3. Disable submit:
  <button type="submit" [disabled]="!rForm.valid || response.success"
                    class="btn btn--circle btn-primary submit-property__button" title="Save">

            </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use **ReactiveForms**.

You can add **controls** (each html input) to a group, using its validators to check if they are valid.
It would take care of all your validation logic underneath and on the submit event all you would have to do to check the form is

```
form.group.valid
```

Also, you can check each control individualy to see if its value has been changed, if the user has clicked on it, etc.

There is more info here https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

***Note:** I can't add comments, that is why I have written this as an answer.

Comment: Ok, I think my question was not clear enough. I already use reactive forms and the change (and touchedI events work great. BUT: A field is only marked as invalid if the field has the class "ng-invalid" AND is "ng-touched". That means, that it´s only marked as invalid if the user interacts with the control (like clicking in it). So when the user opens the form and directly clicks the submit button, the fields are not shown as invalid cause they don´t have the ng-touched class. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: If I set a control with a required validator, then load the page and without interacting with the form print a `form.group.valid` I get `false`. It's possible that I'm missing something, but in my case that works as you want to.

Comment: Yes, you get the "overall form invalid" information but this information is not shown next to the matching field. What I want to achieve is, that the error messages are shown next to the field (like when checked by onChange).